# How do I Interpret a Failed Request Trace?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7, troubleshooting, trace

I have a problem with a web site running IIS 7.  The problem are the initial requests to each page: they take far longer than they should.  After that first request the page loads fine.  I'm sure the subsequent requests only work because of caching.

To troubleshoot the problem I set up failed request tracing.  Here's the relevant portion of a trace:

[image: Trace Image]

You can see the nearly 8 second jump in there.  Any ideas what's going on?  My best guess is a security check of some kind timing out, but I have no idea where to go from here to track it down.

If it helps, the actual site is here:
http://jcoehoorn.dyndns.org/blog/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run a packet capture program on the web server and simultaneously run the trace you ran earlier. If the times reported in the capture and in the trace coincide then it's a server issue. If they don't then it's a network issue.